# Elasticsearch parent child relationship breaking changes from 2.4 to 6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

My earlier implemenation for indexing parent child documents was like below.

index1:

```
{
  "XX": {
    "date_detection": true,
    "_parent": {
      "type": "versiontest"
    },
    "properties": {
      "curatedBy": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

index2:

```
{
  "YY": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "properties": {
      "versionnumber": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "versiondate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have modified the child index with following changes as per the ES 6.2 documentation.

```
{
  "XX": {
    "date_detection": true,
    "properties": {
      "my_join_field": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "YY": "XX"
        }
      },
      "curatedBy": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I see the below error when I try to create the parent and child index and push documents.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [XXtest] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [XX, YY]

Can someone suggest what is not correct here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by the top 'XX' — the type doesn't have anything to do with the relations. You should now use the type `_doc`, which will make the migration easier in 7.0 (the type will then be optional in the API).

IMO your mapping should look something like this:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc" : {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "my-parent": "my-child"
          }
        },
        "curatedBy": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can index data:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/parent1
{
  "curatedBy" : "...",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "my-parent"
  }
}
PUT my-index/_doc/child1?routing=parent1
{
  "curatedBy" : "...",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "my-child",
    "parent": "parent1"
  }
}
```